# How to maintain session based in google sign api using php?

Tags: php, google-signin

I am trying to integrate google signin api using php. Also i should insert users info and other details. For every time should i insert or update userinfo and create session based on the info or can i create the session based on the token without inserting.

```
  if (isset($_GET['code'])) {
    $token = $client->fetchAccessTokenWithAuthCode($_GET['code']);
    $client->setAccessToken($token['access_token']);
    $arr_token = $client->getAccessToken();
    $_SESSION['access_token'] = $arr_token['access_token'];
    // get profile info
    $google_oauth = new Google_Service_Oauth2($client);
    $google_account_info = $google_oauth->userinfo->get();
    $email =  $google_account_info->email;
    $name =  $google_account_info->name;

    //Insert Google AUthentication data in databse
```

Comment: Please show what you have tried so far.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can certainly maintain the user information within session variables without creating a user account. Once the user is authenticated, you can then decide whether to create an account or not depending on the use-case.
Google provide a [helpful guide](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/sign-in) to integrating Google Sign-in. Note they recommend using POST to send the access token, and you appear to be using GET.

Once your user is authenticated, you can create a session:

```
session_start();
```

And then populate SESSION variables which can be interrogated on subsequent pages when creating a user account or for other interactions, for example:

```
    $_SESSION["auth"] = true;
    $_SESSION["googleId"] = $_POST['googleId'];
    $_SESSION["name"] = $_POST['name'];
    $_SESSION["imageURL"] = $_POST['imageURL'];
    $_SESSION["email"] = $_POST['email'];
```

Just make sure to have a session_start(); at the top of each page otherwise you lose the session and also the data.